# How to show the item of a tab with Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I want to make a Pagination control with a tabs of JSON data that I retrives from an AJAX request i pull it on a tabs like this :

I managed to display all the data and show only the 10 first and after the if i click on "page 2" it hide the 10 first and the 10 after to show the 10 that i need; with a max number of 10 per page, and number of page are dynamic, the active page works and i logged in the console the info to make it sure.

But when i click on a page number different than 1 the data are hide, but if i click on the first page it show the data.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xznn-ggD0GU i found this guy and I wanted to do the same but, i may forget something like a bad selected class or id...

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="conTable" class="table-responsive-xl">
    <!-- Tableau de données des mails -->
    <table class="table table-hover table-dark mail">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Date</th>
          <th scope="col">From</th>
          <th scope="col">To</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="ItemMail">
        <!-- Insertion infos des mails avec JQuery/AJAX depuis main.js-->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Pagination -->
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
      <!-- Insertion du Bouton "Previous" -->
      <!-- Insertion du nombres de pages -->
      <!-- Insertion du Bouton "Next" -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

JQuery/JS code which take my data :

```
$("#contTable").toggleClass('d-block table-responsive-xl');

for(ligne in response) {
  console.log(response[ligne].hits)
  var res=response[ligne].hits;

  for(ligne2 in res) {
    var lastEventDate=res[ligne2]._source.last_event_date;
    var from=res[ligne2]._source.from;
    var to=res[ligne2]._source.to;

    $(".ItemMail:last").append(
      "<tr>"+
      "<th scope='row'>"+(increment+=1)+"</th>"+
      "<td>"+lastEventDate+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+from+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+to+"</td>"+
      "</tr>"
    );
  }
}
```

And finally my Pagination code :

```
//Pagination
var TotalMail=response.hits.total;
var limitMailParPage=10;
// cache les mails au dessus du nombre max de limitMailParPage
$(".ItemMail:gt("+(limitMailParPage-1)+")").hide();
// compte le nombre de pages qu'il faudra pou stocker les mails
var nbrDePage=Math.round(TotalMail/limitMailParPage);

// Insertion du nombre 1 pour le mettre en active par défaut
$(".pagination li:first").after("<li class='page-item current active'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>"+1+"</a></li>");

for(var i=2; i<=nbrDePage; i++) {
  $(".pagination li:last").before("<li class='page-item current'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>"+i+"</a></li>");
}

$(".pagination li.current").click(function() {

  if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    var currentIndex=$(this).index();
    $(".pagination li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".ItemMail").hide();

    // marche pas à partir d'ici
    var grandTotal=(limitMailParPage*currentIndex);
    console.log(grandTotal+" GRAND TOTAL");

    for(var i=grandTotal-limitMailParPage; i<grandTotal; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      $(".ItemMail:eq("+i+")").show();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of show hide parent `div` toggle on `tr` . Please refer below code. 
`('.ItemMail')` is your parent div class. You are hiding whole div thats why second page is blank. Try below code and it will solve your problem.

```
var TotalMail=response.hits.total;
var limitMailParPage=10;

// cache les mails au dessus du nombre max de limitMailParPage
$(".ItemMail tr:gt("+(limitMailParPage-1)+")").hide();

// compte le nombre de pages qu'il faudra pou stocker les mails
var nbrDePage=Math.round(TotalMail/limitMailParPage);

// Insertion du nombre 1 pour le mettre en active par défaut
$(".pagination li:first").after("<li class='page-item current active'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>"+1+"</a></li>");

$(".pagination li.current").click(function() {

  if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    var currentIndex=$(this).index();
    $(".pagination li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".ItemMail tr").hide();

    // marche pas à partir d'ici
    var grandTotal=(limitMailParPage*currentIndex);
    console.log(grandTotal+" GRAND TOTAL");

    for(var i=grandTotal-limitMailParPage; i<grandTotal; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      $(".ItemMail tr:eq("+i+")").show();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: i don't unsertand. You want me to replace the show by toogle like this ?`$(".ItemMail:eq("+ i +")").toggle();`

Comment: No. ItemMail is your parent div class. You are hiding whole div thats why second page is blank. Try above code, and it will solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't work. I replace : `$(".ItemMail:eq("+ i +")").show();` by `$(".ItemMail tr:eq("+ i +")").show();` same for `$(".ItemMail").hide();` and `$(".ItemMail:gt("+(limitMailParPage - 1)+")").hide();` with `$(".ItemMail tr").hide();` and `$(".ItemMail tr:gt("+(limitMailParPage - 1)+")").hide();` but nothings changed

Comment: ok mmmh anybody ? i can't get it, it's been 1 week I'm in this issue, but can't find the solution myself, i'm out of option...

Comment: So...i work with elasticsearch for the requestand te data AND it limit the number of my request to 10 by default... after i specified the number of results it works.